# Interested in making a PHP script that increments IP address from defined starting address to defined ending address

Tags: php, ip-address, range

I know I can do this easily by converting the IP addresses to decimal notation first using PHP built in functions like `up2long` and `long2ip`. I just want to be able to do the same using the standard IP address notation as an exercise.

The problem I am thinking goes like this: Given an starting IP address, say 192.168.1.100, and an ending IP address, say 201.130.22.10. Make the program that prints all the address numbers in that range (192.168.1.100, 192.168.1.101, … , 201.130.22.9, 201.130.22.10).

I was thinking that maybe the way to go would be to make a nested `for` loop inside a `while` condition until the first octet of the starting address matches the first octet of the ending address. Then execute the same block of code for the second octet and so on until the program reaches the ending address and finished.

I just started learning to program recently so it is quite possible that my of thinking and or writing code is far from elegant. If you were to this, how would you do it?

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
<?php

// works only for valid range
$start_ip = '10.0.0.1';
$end_ip = '10.0.20.1';

$start_arr = explode('.',$start_ip);
$end_arr = explode('.',$end_ip);

while($start_arr <= $end_arr)
{
    echo implode('.',$start_arr) . '<br>';

    $start_arr[3]++;
    if($start_arr[3] == 256)
    {
        $start_arr[3] = 0;
        $start_arr[2]++;
        if($start_arr[2] == 256)
        {
            $start_arr[2] = 0;
            $start_arr[1]++;
            if($start_arr[1] == 256)
            {
                $start_arr[1] = 0;
                $start_arr[0]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks!!!! it works and I think it is more efficient than the code I was thinhave been writing some code for this but since I was away form the computer I just used pen and paper. Will give it a ago and post it when I have mine. Your script works like a charm, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

This is much less complicated:

```
<?php

// works only for valid range
$start_ip = ip2long('10.0.0.1');
$end_ip = ip2long('10.0.20.1');

while($start_ip <= $end_ip){
  echo long2ip($start_ip).'<br>';
  $start_ip++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInBetweenIPs($startIP,$endIP){

    $subIPS = array();
    $start_ip = ip2long($startIP);
    $end_ip = ip2long($endIP);

    while($start_ip <= $end_ip){
        $subIPS[]=long2ip($start_ip);
        $start_ip++;
    }

    return $subIPS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment (Add to):

```
<?php

function ipinc($i): string {
    $i = explode(".", $i);

    $a = $i[0];
    $b = $i[1];
    $c = $i[2];
    $d = $i[3];

    $d++;

    if ($d > 255) {
        $d = 0;
        $c++;
    }

    if ($c > 255) {
        $c = 0;
        $b++;
    }

    if ($b > 255) {
        $b = 0;
        $a++;
    }

    if ($a > 255) {
        die("IPv4 Range Exceeded");
    }

    return "$a.$b.$c.$d";
}

?>
```

Decrement (Take from):

```
<?php

function ipdec($i) {
    $i = explode(".", $i);

    $a = $i[0];
    $b = $i[1];
    $c = $i[2];
    $d = $i[3];

    $d--;

    if ($d < 0) {
        $d = 255;
        $c--;
    }

    if ($c < 0) {
        $c = 255;
        $b--;
    }

    if ($b < 0) {
        $b = 255;
        $a--;
    }

    if ($a < 0) {
        die("IPv4 Range Exceeded");
    }

    return "$a.$b.$c.$d";
}

?>
```

To test both functions, you can write a for loop to generate approximately 16 million IP addresses back and forth, you can pipe the output to a file and store the results that way.

```
<?php

require 'function.ipinc.php';
require 'function.ipdec.php';

print("Increment:\n");
for ($i = 0, $ip = "100.0.0.0"; $i <= 16777215; $i++) {
    print("$ip\n");
    $ip = ipinc($ip);
}
print("----------\n");

print("Decrement:\n");
for ($i = 0, $ip = "100.255.255.255"; $i <= 16777215; $i++) {
    print("$ip\n");
    $ip = ipdec($ip);
}
print("----------\n");

die("Finished!\n");

?>
```

If you don't like assigning values through variable declarations, modify the functions so you can use [pass by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead.